# Should I tell a commenter that I've edited my post? If so, how?

Tags: discussion, edits, notifications

Often I'll get comments asking for an explanation / expansion of an answer.

Am I right to @notify the commenter when I've edited?

I do this because if I were the commenter I wouldn't want to keep checking, not knowing when/if the poster is going to update.

Is there a way to get updates re. favourited posts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, if you have received a comment asking for an update, expansion, or explanation, then it is entirely appropriate to post another comment directed at the user once you have made a change.

If you are worried about noise associated with excessive comments, you are of course free to come back hours / days / weeks later and remove any of your comments that no longer serve a purpose.

Comment: The original commenter could also flag both comments as obsolete if they revisit the question and determine it's now suitable.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's fine to post an

> @person: updated answer

comment. In the past, people have done this when I've just asked them for clarification/expansion (re: link-only answers). I appreciate the notification because, in cases of good answers and edits, I always upvote afterward.

Answer (score -6):

I think in most cases you should tell people that you made an edit. If you just posted the question and had to edit it because of some mistakes, then no you shouldn't post that you've edited it. But whenever I edit a post and feel the need to show that I have editted the post, I do it like this.

Stuff before edit

---

Edit:

Stuff after edit

Comment: I'm assuming if the commenter sees the edited post they will know i've edited it. My question is related to how do they know i've edited, without having to keep checking.

Comment: Also, doesn't that go against the idea that posts aren't for a person, they're for people (so edits should really be inline, not disjointed to keep the flow of the post).

Comment: Doing it this way is inferior to just making edits and leaving a post in a cohesive form. The edit history is accessible by everybody, so it's always easy to tell what changed between versions.